# TypeError: register_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

I have such problem with urlpatterns. I'm trying to answer for frontend a json file,but when i running a server, i got a typeerror, is it possible to test my code without HttpResponse or render?
Here is my code
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from backend.views import register_user

urlpatterns = [

    path(r'^register', register_user()),
]
```

How should i construct my urls and json responses to run the server successfully

views.py

```
from backend.models import RegistrationForm, AuthenticationForm
from backend.responses import Responses


def register_user(request):
  if request.POST:
    form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      user = form.save()
      name = form.cleaned_data['username']
      surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
      email = form.cleaned_data['email']
      password = form.cleaned_data['password']
      user = User.objects.create(
        first_name=name,
        last_name=surname,
        email=email,
        is_active=False
      )
      user.set_password(password)
      send_account_activation_email(request, user)
      activate_user_account()
      return Responses.ok_response(301)
    else:
      form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    return Responses.ok_response(200)
```

responses.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


class Responses:

  def error_response(self, error, text):
    comments = [{'success': False, 'error': {'code': error, 'message': text}}]
    return JsonResponse({'comments': comments})

  def ok_response(self, code):
    comments = [{'success': True, 'code': code}]
    return JsonResponse({'comments': comments})
```

models.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    name_of_company = forms.CharField(label="Company name", max_length=30)
    country = forms.CharField(label="Country")
    city = forms.CharField(label="City/Town")

    '''logo_base64 = models.ImageField'''

    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label="Description")

    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput, label="Email", max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=32)
    check_password = forms.CharField(label="Repeat password", max_length=32)
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as any other view. You shouldn't be calling the view in the URLconf; just `path(r'^register', register_user),`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are wiring up the ***function based view***, you don't need to be **call** it. So, remove the parenthesis

```
from django.urls import path
from backend.views import register_user

urlpatterns = [

    path(r'^register', register_user),
]
```

Bottom Note:
I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401856/defining-views-and-urls-in-django-why-arent-parenthesis-used-to-call-the-funct) which explians why you don't need to call the FBV with paranthesis. Hope it helps :)